# Run command in next gnome-terminal tab

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I want to be able to open a new terminal tab in the **current** terminal window and run a command in the *new* terminal tab from a script. Note that I don't want to open an entirely new terminal window, just a new tab.

Running the following opens a new tab as desired, but the `echo` command gets run in the terminal that executed the script as opposed to getting run in the new tab

```
#temp.sh
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
echo 'hi'
```

If there's anyway to do this without using Tmux I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Newest gnome-terminal versions support

```
gnome-terminal --tab [-e command ...]
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this but this isn't what I was looking for. This opens a new terminal window as opposed to a new tab in the *current* terminal

Comment: That's what it does _in recent versions_, e.g. in Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still on Ubuntu 16.04